# Best way to groups cells in 3D numpy array by proximity

Tags: numpy

I'm trying to find the best way to find/set all cells surrounding a 3D location.  This is sort of a clustering problem.  I would like to cluster 'groups' of cells around a few particular locations.

For example, given a cell distance of 2, a 3D array of (4,4,4), and a list of 3D locations:

```
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 2, 0)
(3, 0, 0)
```

Assume the given array is all zeros.

I'd like to return a 3D array that has 1 in all the cells that are within the cell distance of 2 from any location.

So, any cell that is 2 or less away from the above locations (including the location itself) should have a 1 in it.

I want to use numpy slicing instead of a Python for loops for performance.

Here's a sample input and output:

```
distance = 2
shape = (4, 4, 4)
locations = [(2, 0, 0)]
```

return should be:

```
array([[[1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]]], dtype=int32)
```

Essentially a cube of size 2x2x2 is formed around the 'central' point (2, 0, 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
import numpy as np

distance = 2
shape = (4, 4, 4)
locations = np.array([(2, 0, 0)])

data = np.zeros(shape, np.int)

data[locations[:,0], locations[:,1], locations[:,2]] = 1

import scipy.ndimage
scipy.ndimage.binary_dilation(data, np.ones((3,3,3)), 2)
```

Comment: I tried it briefly and it looks correct.  However, I don't quite understand what's going on with np.ones(3,3,3) and binary_dilation.  Could you provide a layman's description?  The scipy docs were a little dense.  It looks like np.ones(3,3,3) is the size of the 'cube' that's needed. So it should depend on distance right?

Comment: Yeah; the ones are the 'stencil'. The nice thing about this approach over writing to a sliced cube, for instance, is that you can also use more complicated stencils, which are not cubes.